# Swift Dispatch Main

Tags: swift, program-entry-point, dispatch

I have code that I am repeating a bunch.  I want to update things on the main thread, UI stuff.

```
public func closeGraph() {
   DispatchQueue.main.sync{_closeGraph()}
}
```

That's easy enough, but what if user interaction triggers it and I am already on the main thread.  ++ungood.

```
public func closeGraph() {
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        _closeGraph()
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync{_closeGraph()}
    }
}
```

Oops openGraph() throws...

```
public func openGraph() throws  {
    do {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            try _openGraph()
        } else {
            try DispatchQueue.main.sync{try _openGraph()}
        }
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to this so i don't have to copy paste it everywhere?

Comment: I've worked with code like that and I consider it a symptom of a bigger problem.  I suggest it's better for the caller to know which thread it's on and do the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract your check to a generic function like this:

```
public func mainQueue(execute block: () throws -> Void) rethrows {
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        try block()
    } else {
        try DispatchQueue.main.sync{ try block() }
    }
}
```

then if your `_closeGraph()` function doesn't throw any error, your code will be like this:

```
public func closeGraph() {
    mainQueue(execute: _closeGraph)
}
```

and if your `_closeGraph()` function `throws`, your code will be like this:

```
public func closeGraph() {
    do {
        try mainQueue(execute: _closeGraph)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

As you can see you will need to write the handling of the throwing function every time.

**Update**: If you have a generic error handling in mind, you can hide  the `do-catch` statement in `mainQueue(execute:)` function like this:

```
public func mainQueue(execute block: () throws -> Void) {
    do {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            try block()
        } else {
            try DispatchQueue.main.sync{ try block() }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

then calling this function will be the same whether the `_closeGraph()` function is throwing or not:

```
public func closeGraph() {
    mainQueue(execute: _closeGraph)
}
```